# Perl XML::LibXML returning different results on different systems

Tags: xml, perl, libxml2

I have a Linux Mint 17 system running perl v5.18.2, with a simple script to fetch some XML:

```
use XML::LibXML;

$url='http://forecast.weather.gov/MapClick.php?lat=39.82390&lon=-97.64500&unit=0&lg=english&FcstType=dwml';

$parser = XML::LibXML->new();

$docFetched = $parser->parse_file($url);

print $docFetched;
```

It returns a full page of XML, which is what I want.

However, when I run this same script on another system (CentOS 6.4) with perl v5.10.1, I get the following:

XML::LibXML::Document=SCALAR(0x1253e40)

What might be the problem?

Any help would be great.

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Recent versions of [`XML::LibXML`](https://metacpan.org/pod/XML::LibXML) overload stringification; older versions do not.

Upgrade XML::LibXML on your CentOS machine, or else, just call `$docFetched->toString` to get back a string of XML.

Comment: @joseph85750 Welcome to StackOverflow!  Be sure to give this answer the checkmark if it successfully solves your question.